# System.TypeLoadException in System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog (C#)

Tags: c#, exception

I'm having problem when running my Windows Forms program.

In the program, I have a button that calls OpenFileDialog's ShowDialog() everytime it clicked.

```
public partial class MyProgram : Form
{
  private Button myButton;
  private OpenFileDialog openFD;
  private string filePath;
  public MyProgram()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    myButton = new Button();
    openFD = new OpenFileDialog();
    filePath = string.Empty;
    myButton.Text = "Browse";
    myButton.Click += new EventHandler(ShowOpenDialog);
  }
  private ShowOpenDialog(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if(openFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // Here
    {
      filePath = openFD.FileName;
    }
  }
}
```

But when I run the program, everytime I clicked the "Browse" (myButton) button, I got a "MyProgram has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience." error. When I clicked on the "What data does this error report contain?" link, the Error signature contains

```
EventType : clr20r3     P1 : myprogram.exe     P2 : 1.0.0.0     P3 : 4a49b0bf
P4 : system.windows.forms     P5 : 2.0.0.0     P6 : 4889dee7     P7 : 188f     
P8 : 32     P9 : system.typeloadexception
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241883.aspx), a TypeLoadException refers to a failure to load a type from an assembly.

I believe that you don't have a suitable version of WinForms installed.  What version of .NET and WinForms are you trying to use?

The most basic solution, however, would likely be to reinstall the .NET framework.

Comment: But I have no problem when running other .NET applications that uses OpenFileDialog. I have .NET Framework 1.1, 2.0 SP2, 3.0 SP2, and 3.5 SP1 installed. with Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition as the IDE. How to get WinForms version?

Comment: Additional information: I selected .NET Framework 2.0 as the Target Framework in the Project Properties

Comment: @djzmo To get your Winforms version, go to the Solution Explorer, expand the References item, right-click System.Windows.Forms and click "Properties".  Although, the code worked when I ran it on my machine, so it's likely a DLL hell problem on your end.